# why does max_by_key with i32.log10() causing "attempt to add with overflow"

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get the max number of digits in an i32 array. I'm using log10(n) + 1 as my formula to calculate how many digits an i32 has and I thought I would just be able to use that within a max_by_key, but I am getting

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow', /mnt/f/Personal-Docs/Repos/radix_sort_rs/src/lib/lib.rs:9:60
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Here's my code:

```
fn get_max_digits<const N: usize>(arr: [i32; N]) -> i32 {
    return *arr.iter().max_by_key(|a| a.log10() + 1).unwrap();
}
```

I'm still new to rust so sorry if this is a simple question.

Comment: Can't reproduce - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c74429bca93d08301536cfde0402e43. Could you share a more complete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my question not too long after posting. I was trying to do a logarithm of 0 causing undefined. I believe the attempt to add with overflow is the current interaction with 0i32.log10() as it is a nightly only feature.

Comment: This is documented behavior, in fact - https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/primitive.i32.html#method.log10 explicitly states that `0.log10()` panics in debug mode.

Comment: Since this question was raised to top... Please mark this as the answer.